# Get return value of Linux syscall with GCC inline assembly

Tags: linux, gcc, x86-64, system-calls, inline-assembly

The following macro can perform the `lstat` system call.

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define m_lstat(PATH, FS){                   \
  long         _rax  = 6;  /*sys_newlstat*/  \
  uint8_t*     _path = PATH;                 \
  struct stat* _fs   = FS;                   \
  asm volatile(                              \
    "movq %0, %%rax\n"                       \
    "movq %1, %%rdi\n"                       \
    "movq %2, %%rsi\n"                       \
    "syscall"                                \
    :                                        \
    :"m"(_rax), "m"(_path), "m"(_fs)         \
    :"rax", "rdi", "rsi"                     \
  );                                         \
}
```

One can call it like the glibc wrapper `lstat`:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  struct stat fs0;  m_lstat("a.out", &fs0);  printf("nbytes %d\n", fs0.st_size);
  struct stat fs1;  lstat(  "a.out", &fs1);  printf("nbytes %d\n", fs1.st_size);
}
```

---

What if I want to access the return value, however? I think it gets written to `rax`, but I don't know how to retrieve it from C code...

For example, the following does *not* work:

```
#define m_lstat(PATH, FS){                   \
  long         _rax  = 6;  /*sys_newlstat*/  \
  u8*          _path = PATH;                 \
  struct stat* _fs   = FS;                   \
  int ret;                                   \
  asm volatile(                              \
    "movq %0, %%rax\n"                       \
    "movq %1, %%rdi\n"                       \
    "movq %2, %%rsi\n"                       \
    "syscall"                                \
    :"=m"(ret)                               \
    :"m"(_rax), "m"(_path), "m"(_fs)         \
    :"rax", "rdi", "rsi"                     \
  );                                         \
  printf("ret %d\n", ret);                   \
}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete; how can one reproduce it?

Comment: This code at the godbolt link should work: https://godbolt.org/z/yfpbE2 . `syscall` instruction itself clobbers RCX and R11. I use the appropriate registers for the constraints rather than using `m` (`S`=RSI, `D`=RDI). I use an output and input constraint where I tie the input constraint to the same register (RAX) as the output constraint. This allows passing a value in via one variable and out via another. I also use a memory clobber since I am passing the address of data (in RSI and RDI) and have to make sure the compiler realizes that data in memory before the inline assembly is called.

Comment: @tansy I've added some boilerplate so that you can actually compile it.

Comment: You almost never want to use explicit mov instructions in inline asm -- its at best wasteful and inefficient, and often broken if you don't get the clobbers just right.  Instead you want to use constraints.  Try `asm volatile("syscall" : "=a" (ret) : "a" (_rax), "D" (_path), "S" (_fs));`

Comment: As an addition to what Michael did (which looks good), I might add a `const` for _rax & _path.  It won't change the resulting code, but it's possible your path is already a const and (unnecessarily) casting it back non-const to make this call would be silly.  And doesn't lstat get the return value for you (errno)?  What value do you get from doing this with inline asm?

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Close, but you forgot clobbers on RCX and R11.  Also a `"memory"` clobber or dummy output operand because it writes a `struct stat` that is only *pointed to* by one of the inputs, not otherwise declared as an operand.

Comment: Michael's and Chris's solutions worked!

Answer (score 2):

*Updated following @PeterCordes @MichaelPetch comments*

Just use proper constrains

```
inline long m_lstat(char *_path, struct stat *_fs)
{
    long _rax = 6;

    asm volatile(
        "syscall"
        : "+a" (_rax)
        : "D" (_path), "S" (_fs) 
        : "rcx", "r11", /* used by syscall */
          "memory"      /* barrier for _path and _fs */
    );

    return _rax;
}
```

This code

```
struct stat s;
char foo[] = "foo";

long test()
{
    return m_lstat(foo, &s);
}
```

produces

```
test:
    movl    $6, %eax
    leaq    foo(%rip), %rdi
    leaq    s(%rip), %rsi
#APP
# 10 "m_lst.c" 1
    syscall
# 0 "" 2
#NO_APP
    ret
```

I used this code for testing, all works fine

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    struct stat fs;
    long ret;
    char *p = argv[ argc >= 2 ];

    ret = lstat(p, &fs);
    printf("lstat:   %s: ret = %ld, size = %zd\n", p, ret, fs.st_size);

    ret = m_lstat(p, &fs);
    printf("m_lstat: %s: ret = %ld, size = %zd\n", p, ret, fs.st_size);

    return 0;
}
```

p.s. If for some reasons you want to use macro, not inline function, you should use another syntax:

```
#define m_lstat(_path, _fs) \
({                          \
    long _rax = 6;          \
    asm volatile (          \
        "syscall"           \
        : "+a" (_rax)       \
        : "D" (_path), "S" (_fs) \
        : "rcx", "r11", "memory" \
    );                      \
    _rax;                   \
})
```

Comment: Close, but read the comments on the question: you forgot the RCX and R11 clobbers (inherent in using `syscall`), and you forgot a `"memory"` clobber or dummy memory output operand to tell the compiler the memory *pointed-to* by the inputs are also an input and an output respectively.  (You can break your version in practice by using a local array as the input: gcc will optimize away the "dead" stores of string bytes because you haven't told it anything reads it.)  See also the MUSL libc syscall2 macro for a working example.

Comment: @PeterCordes, thanks. I will read about the `syscall`, do tests and update my answer.

Comment: @étale-cohomology I'm wrong indeed here. I use inline assembly in simpler cases.

Comment: My comment under the question also mentioned RCX and R11. The `syscall` instruction is documented here: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/syscall  . RCX is clobbered with the address of the instruction after `syscall` and R11 is clobbered by having the state of RFLAGS saved to it. Because they are clobbered you need to tell the inline assembly that RCX and R11 are potentially modified by adding them to the clobbers list.

Comment: Like Peter, under the question I mention the issue with the lack of `memory` as a clobber (or a dummy constraint for the path since it is an array of characters that make up the path). Here is an example on godbolt that doesn't use a `memory` clobber that doesn't work properly: https://godbolt.org/z/fk4Ucb  . `./output.s` is the name of the output program in godbolt. When run it should return 0 (value in RAX). The problem is that it doesn't. If you look at the generated assembly the file name on the stack for variable `p` is never set to contain `./output.s` m_lstat returns an error value.

Comment: Now compare that with the version that has a `memory` clobber added: https://godbolt.org/z/dpVmtS . When run the program returns 0 as expected. You'll also find that the variable `p` is initialized on the stack by programmatically building the file name `./output.s` on the stack as you would expect.

Comment: @étale-cohomology: The dangerous thing about this answer is that it happens to work for some cases (because the `"+a"`, `"D"`, and `"S"` constraints are right), but can break when you change the surrounding code and/or compile with optimization enabled (because of missing clobbers).  Chris's comment under the question has the same problem.  **Testing is not sufficient to prove inline-asm correct.**  Mistakes are easy to make, and can be hard to test for.  But when you see them, it's not hard to construct test-cases where lying to the compiler does break in practice.  e.g. path = local array.

Comment: An example that can break with `-O1` or greater optimizations levels (when not specifying RCX as a clobber on the syscall) with most versions of GCC can be found here: https://godbolt.org/z/u2h9o- .  That example has a function `setsix` that I call before `m_lstat`. It is a simple function with inline assembler that is simply used to return a value of 6 (but done through the RCX register). I then check that the value that `setsix` returns is still the same after `m_lstat` returns. If they are different it was because RCX was unexpectedly modified. At `-O0` optimization level it should work.

Comment: If you add `RCX` to the clobber list of `m_lstat`'s inline assembly it works as expected with or without optimizations and prints success. The same thing applies to R11. You need to add both to the clobber list inside `m_lstat`

Comment: PeterCordes, MichaelPetch, Thanks for the lesson.

Answer (score -1):

If you remove `printf();` call, you get this:

```
.LC0:
        .string "test.txt"
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 56
.LBB2: // m_lstats
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], 6 // _rax  = 6;
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], OFFSET FLAT:.LC0 // _path = PATH;
        lea     rax, [rbp-176] // _fs = FS;
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-24], rax
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8] // %rax = _rax
        mov     rdx, QWORD PTR [rbp-16] // %rdx = _path
        mov     rsi, QWORD PTR [rbp-24] // %rsi = _fs
        mov     rdi, rdx // %rdi = _path
        syscall // call
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-28], eax // ret = %eax (low %rax)
.LBE2: // back to main
        mov     eax, 0 // return 0; // @ main()
        leave
        ret
```

all the rest is just preparation for `printf();` (back to printf)

```
.LC0:
        .string "test.txt"
.LC1:
        .string "ret %d\n"
(...)
        syscall // call
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-28], eax // (*)ret = %eax (low %rax)
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-28] // %esi = &ret
        mov     esi, eax //
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1 // %edi = &"ret %d\n"
        mov     eax, 0 // %eax = 0 // ?
        call    printf
```

So you do get your return value in `ret` (`mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-28], eax`) and as you said returned value is in `%rax`.
Therefore you should be able to access `ret` like any normal variable.

PS. Hope you don't mind intel syntax mixed with `%reg`, % is to indicate register in opposition to variable. I know there won't be `rax` variable but to make it more readable I used this decoration.

Comment: Thanks! But I still get nothing in `ret`... Something must be off with my GCC inline assembly... maybe the `"=m"(ret)` part...

Comment: Do you absolutely need it inlined? What if you made this function a module? You would do it in assembly and call it from C.